# How to instantiate a collection.mutable.Map[String, Any] in scala?

Tags: scala

I want to build a map ieratively So I have taken a mutable map. I want to initialize this with empty values.

I have tried this

```
      val resultingMap: collection.mutable.Map[String, Any] = _
```

But it assigns `null` to resultingMap and hence when I try to add a record to it, It rightfully throws an exception.

So I tried a hacky way like this

```
      val resultingMap: collection.mutable.Map[String, Any] = collection.mutable.Map("" -> "")
```

It works but I would like to use a better + standard approach of doing this.

Comment: Note that `Any` isn't a useful type as you'll most likely need to `cast` (a dangerous run-time operation) it in order to make use of that type. Using `Any` is certainly a code smell in Scala given the danger of run-time casting.

Comment: What provoked you to add the `"" -> ""` mapping?

Comment: @ChrisMartin As I mentioned I just tried to create the Map with any set of values and `"" -> ""` is just a imaginary pair

Comment: Haven't you tried to just not pass any pair? `collection.mutable.Map()` works. Consider using immutable map with some more specific type than `Any`. You rarely *actually* need what you want to create.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Map.empty[A, B]` create creates an empty `Map` with no key value pairs in it.

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

val resultingMap: Map[String, Any] = Map.empty[String, Any]
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.collection.mutable._

scala> Map.empty[String, Any]
res29: Map[String, Any] = Map()

scala> val map = Map.empty[String, Any]
map: Map[String, Any] = Map()
```